# Significance of multiple <script> tags for old Google AdSense code

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

I'm working on some old pages with Google AdSense inline scripts:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-1234123412345");
  GS_googleEnableAllServices();
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-1234123412345", "Header_728x90");
  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-1234123412345", "TopCube_300x250");
  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-1234123412345", "BottomCube_300x250");
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  GA_googleFetchAds();
</script>
```

While refactoring this page, I thought I would clean that up a bit by removing some unneeded opening/closing `<script>` tags:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-1234123412345");
  GS_googleEnableAllServices();
  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-1234123412345", "Header_728x90");
  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-1234123412345", "TopCube_300x250");
  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-1234123412345", "BottomCube_300x250");
  GA_googleFetchAds();
</script>
```

After my modifications, Chrome reports an error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GA_googleAddSlot is not defined

I don't understand the significant difference between the original code, and the refactored version.  What does the browser do differently for multiple inline script tags vs. a single one in this case?

Comment: This may be a duplicate question. I see an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559652/how-to-combine-inline-javascripts-into-one