# How to combine inline JavaScripts into one?

Tags: javascript

I'm fixing up a template we're using on one of our sites which has the following code

This snippet works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-123");
  GS_googleEnableAllServices();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-123", "Foo");
  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-123", "Bar");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  GA_googleFetchAds();
</script>
```

I've tried concatenating the static scripts like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-123");
  GS_googleEnableAllServices();

  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-123", "Foo");
  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-123", "Bar");

  GA_googleFetchAds();
</script>
```

However, now I'm getting an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: GA_googleAddSlot is not defined
```

I'm no noob when it comes to JavaScript stuff, but I can't imagine why combining the 3 inline scripts into a single `<script>` tag would make any difference here.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if one of the previous `GA_` calls (in the *first* block) adds a *dynamic* script element? - Which is the only reason I can think of for the behavior, should it be reported correctly. If it does then combining the current SCRIPT elements (at least those two) won't work. Combining the last two SCRIPTs should work just fine.

Comment: Could this be a timing issue? Maybe GS_googleAddAdSenseService(XXX); or GS_googleEnableAllServices(); hasn't finished before you call AddSlot?

Comment: @bobbyg603 but it's not like a second `<script>` block would wait for the first `<script>` block to finish, right?

Comment: It might, I don't have a definite answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`google_service.js` does not define `GA_googleAdSlot`, but it defines `GS_googleEnableAllServices`. When `GS_googleEnableAllServices` is called, it uses `document.write` to insert a new script element which loads a definition of `GA_googleAdSlot`. The new script element is inserted in the document after the end of the script element currently being executed. It's complicated, but it's your answer.

Comment: I was just digging through the code too. Thanks, yeah, it's complicated (even stupid) but that's just the way it works in this case. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/112649?hl=en

This is the piece of the document support:

DFP Small Business requires distinct blocks of JavaScript, described below. **Do not combine JavaScript blocks, or your code may break.**

They have clearly mentioned that you **should not** combine Javascript blocks!

I am not sure why, but as long as it is mentioned in the document, you have to follow the rules.